# Embedding live HLS stream on website for PC, Mac, iOS, Android

Tags: stream, video-streaming, embed, jwplayer, flowplayer

i have this stream:

http://stream1.seenstream.com:1935/live/SpkEsy-AppWI.stream/playlist.m3u8

I have JW Player 6 premium but it just flash crashes upon trying to load.

We can get the stream to load on PCs embedding it with VLC. Also, on a Mac in Safari only, iOS, and some androids, embedding it with HTML5. But i was hoping for kind of a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this stream with the player?

Comment: As a test, have you tried using hls.js?